# Vim: How Can I Have Relative Line Numbers but Replace the Current Line With the True Line Number

Tags: vim, line-numbers

If I set `relativenumber`, then Vim will show relative line numbers.
And the current line will show as `0`.
But I would like for it to show the actual line number.
I know that I can simply set both `relativenumber` and `number`, I can achieve this.
But the issue is that it will waste horizontal space by reserving a column specifically for the actual number and have a separate column for the relative numbers.
I do not want that.
I simply want to change the `0` to the current line number.

Answer (score 0):

> But the issue is that it will waste horizontal space by reserving a column specifically for the actual number and have a separate column for the relative numbers. I do not want that.

Well, it's a good thing that Vim doesn't work like that at all, then.

Instead of imagining things in your head, how about reading the documentation: `:help 'number'` and `:help 'relativenumber'` and *actually* do things?

[image: nu rnu]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to read the documentation because I did not know the `numberwidh` option existed. Thanks for being kind about it.

Comment: It turns out that `numberwidth` is **not** the option I'm looking for. Because if you set a value lower than four, it will mess up when a file has more than 99 lines. What I want is for the line number to **always** be aligned to the right along with the relative numbers.

Comment: @Amarakon This is currently not possible. See https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1875